# How to know which Traffic manager endpoint served the request

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

My traffic manager with performance routing method has two endpoints.They are in different region. I wanted to validate when I make a request to webpage, which endpoints served that requests. Is there a way to validate that, like any third party website or some tool in Azure itself?

Comment: Traffic Manager Real User Measurements might be a option or answer for your query refer to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-rum-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Traffic View to achieve the purpose. In Azure portal, find your Traffic Manager. Then click Traffic view in left and enable Traffic view.

After that, you can check **DNS QUERY SOURCE IP** and **ENDPOINT** to see where the request come from and which endpoint serve this request.

The result likes this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, just now I saw that. It was showing only one end point all the time, so was the confusion. I disabled and enabled again, now I can see both endpoints and traffic. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad that my answer can help you.:-)